# How to use pstricks with expex to draw arrows in examples?

Tags: pstricks, arrows, examples, expex

I'm using the expex package to write examples (in linguistics articles). This package, according to the documentation, allows one to draw arrows (to represent movement in syntax). There is a section about pstricks to do this p. 74 of the documentation on the expex package.

Here is a minimal working example (copied and pasted from the expex documention) that I cannot get to compile and I don't understand why.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{pstricks} % Apparently this is required to draw arrow with Expex (see p.74 of Expec doc)
\usepackage{expex}  % package for glosses
\lingset{everygla=,aboveglftskip=0pt,*=?*, textoffset=!-.6em, everyglb=\footnotesize, everyglft=\slshape} % changes style of glosses



\begin{document}


\ex
This is a "control item", showing that the problem really comes from adding the stuff to draw arrows.
\xe

\ex
%\pss{angle=-90,nodesep=0pt,arrows=->,dima=.2em,labelsep=.25ex,linearc=.7ex}
\def\\#1(#2){\rnode{#2}{\strut #1}} %
%
\vrule height0pt depth5.3ex width0pt
\\Whom(A) did John persuade \\t(B) [ PRO to visit \\whom(C) ]
\ncbar[armA=3.5ex,offsetB=\lingdima]{B}{A}
\bput{0}{$M_{sp}=2$}
\ncbar[armA=4.5ex,offsetB=-\lingdima]{C}{A}
\bput{0}(1.2){$M_{sp}=6$}
\xe


\end{document}
```

The result should look like this. (This snapshot is taken from the expex documentation p 74.)

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I add `\usepackage{pst-node}` to the file, then it compiles, but it does not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

If using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) is an option, this can be easily done:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\lingset{everygla=,aboveglftskip=0pt,*=?*, textoffset=!-.6em, everyglb=\footnotesize, everyglft=\slshape}

\newcommand\Tikzmark[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};%
}

\NewDocumentCommand\DrawArrow{O{}mmmmO{3}}{
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[->,rounded corners,line width=0.8pt,shorten >= 2pt,shorten <= 2pt,#1] 
    (#2) -- ++(0,-#6\ht\strutbox) coordinate (aux) -- node[#4] {#5} (#3|-aux) -- (#3);
}

\begin{document}

\ex
W\Tikzmark{enda}{h}\Tikzmark{endb}{o}m(A) did John persuade \Tikzmark{starta}{t}(B) [ PRO to visit w\Tikzmark{startb}{h}om(C) ]
\xe
\DrawArrow{starta}{enda}{above}{$M_{sp}=2$}
\DrawArrow{startb}{endb}{above,pos=0.15}{$M_{sp}=6$}[3.5]

\end{document}
```

You use `\Tikzmark` to place some marks and then `\DrawArrow` to draw the arrow between the marks.

The `\DrawArrow` command has syntax

```
\DrawArrow[<tikz options>]{<start-mark>}{<end-mark>}{<options for the node>}{<label>}[<vertical shift>]
```