# Movement arrows in gloss (part IV)

Tags: tikz-arrows, linguistics, gb4e, gloss

In reference to this question:

[Movement arrows in gloss (part III)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353116/movement-arrows-in-gloss-part-iii)

I have one more question:

Is it possible to get four arrows: Two beneath the text in both directions and two above. Up to now there are only two arrows for the two directions... :(

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{gb4e}           

\newlength{\arrowht}
\setlength{\arrowht}{-2.5ex}
\newcommand*\exdepthstrut{{\vrule height 0pt depth -\arrowht width 0pt}}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)] \node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (#1) {#1\exdepthstrut};}

% This code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068/2693
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}

% Thanks to Paul Gessler and Percusse for code improvement here
\newcommand{\arrow}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt] (#1.base) to [ncbar=\arrowht] (#2.base);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
    \ex Example 1
        \gll ~\tikzmark{lachend} ~sagte sie \tikzmark{t} das\\
            [VF ][LSK][ MF {} {} ]\\
            \arrow{t}{lachend}  
            \ex Example 2
        \gll  und ~hob sie t ~~auf schrecklich weinend\\
            {}  [LSK][ MF \tikzmark{t} ][RSK][ \tikzmark{NF} {} ]\\
            \arrow{t}{NF}   
\end{exe}
          \end{document}
```

[image]