# Line break in lstlisting inside of escaped text

Tags: listings

I' trying to fix the display of a line break inside an lstlisting environment, but more specifically in a part of the listing that is inside an escaped area:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{}


\definecolor{keywordColor}{HTML}{0033B3}
\definecolor{parameterColor}{HTML}{067D17}
\definecolor{commentColor}{HTML}{8C8C8C}
\definecolor{scenarioColor}{HTML}{871094}

\newcommand{\lstKeyword}[1]{{\textcolor{keywordColor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lstParameter}[1]{{\textcolor{parameterColor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lstScenario}[1]{{\textcolor{scenarioColor}{\textit{#1}}}}

\lstdefinestyle{bddStory}
{
  frame=single,
  captionpos=b,
  commentstyle=\color{commentColor},
  keywordstyle=\color{keywordColor},
  morekeywords={Given ,When ,Then ,And ,Narrative,Examples},
  escapeinside={<@}{@>},
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
  breakatwhitespace=true
}

\title{Example Issue}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=bddStory]
<@\lstScenario{Scenario: A scenario title is too long and can't fit into a single line which causes issues in the highlighting}@>
Given there is some further content
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The content is renderd as follows - the two breaks in the box and the missing arrow in the new line is the issue:

[image: wrong rendering of new line]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This segmented box is a known bug in `listings` package. You can use `tcolorbox`'s `listings` patch to fix it. Notice that the way arguments are passed to `listings` package is different.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable, listings}

\definecolor{keywordColor}{HTML}{0033B3}
\definecolor{parameterColor}{HTML}{067D17}
\definecolor{commentColor}{HTML}{8C8C8C}
\definecolor{scenarioColor}{HTML}{871094}

\newcommand{\lstKeyword}[1]{{\textcolor{keywordColor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lstParameter}[1]{{\textcolor{parameterColor}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\lstScenario}[1]{{\textcolor{scenarioColor}{\textit{#1}}}}

\lstdefinestyle{bddStory}
{
  captionpos=b,
  commentstyle=\color{commentColor},
  keywordstyle=\color{keywordColor},
  morekeywords={Given ,When ,Then ,And ,Narrative,Examples},
  escapeinside={<@}{@>},
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space},
  breakatwhitespace=true
}

\title{Example Issue}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[1]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  listing only,
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  sharp corners,
  top=0mm,
  bottom=0mm,
  left=2mm,
  right=2mm,
  boxsep=0mm,
  colframe=black,
  colback=white,
  listing options={
    style=#1
  }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{mylisting}{bddStory}
<@\lstScenario{Scenario: A scenario title is too long and can't fit into a single line which causes issues in the highlighting}@>
Given there is some further content
\end{mylisting}


\end{document}
```

As for the missing arrow, I think `listings` package does not try to add `postbreak` contents to escaped region. See the example below:

[image]

If you *really* want to implement this feature, I find these two posts:

- [Insert word, character, or symbol at beginning of all hanging indents in paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427957/insert-word-character-or-symbol-at-beginning-of-all-hanging-indents-in-paragra)
- [Insert a character at beginning of each line after the current one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202231/insert-a-character-at-beginning-of-each-line-after-the-current-one)

Comment: do you happen to know how standard captions available in the listings package can be supported by the tcolorbox package?

Comment: @schneida As for captions, you can refer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391901/how-to-create-my-own-caption-type-with-declarecaptiontype-on-memoir-class). Basically, put listing in your custom environment.